# Project Euler #37: my solution is too slow

Tags: haskell, optimization, primes

I am toying with project euler problem 37. The problem is stated as follows:

> The number 3797 has an interesting property. Being prime itself, it is possible to continuously remove digits from left to right, and remain prime at each stage: 3797, 797, 97, and 7. Similarly we can work from right to left: 3797, 379, 37, and 3.
>
> Find the sum of the only eleven primes that are both truncatable from left to right and right to left.
>
> NOTE: 2, 3, 5, and 7 are not considered to be truncatable primes.

This is my code:

```
import Data.Char

prime n
    | n < 2                                                                       = False
    | n == 2                                                                      = True
    | length [x | x <- [2..(floor . sqrt $ fromIntegral n)], n `mod` x == 0] == 0 = True
    | otherwise                                                                   = False

truncateList xs = take (length xs) $ iterate init xs

truncateSteps n = truncateList nn ++ truncateList rn
            where
                nn = map digitToInt $ show n
                rn = reverse nn

truncatablePrime n = and $ map (\ns -> prime $ foldl (\x y -> 10 * x + y) 0 ns) $ truncateSteps n

main = print $ sum $ take 11 $ [n | n <- [9,11..], notElem 5 $ map digitToInt $ show n, truncatablePrime n]
```

I believe that my code will yield the correct result if it would finish. It is simply all too slow. I have optimized a few things, like not counting numbers that contain the digit '5' and only checking for 'primeness' up to the square root of the number, but it is not enough at all.

I would like some hints to other optimizations I could look into. Now, keep in mind that I am a new acquantance of haskell, but do suggest anything you think is worth a mention.

**UPDATE**
This is the finished solution which runs in just about 1 second on my machine: https://gist.github.com/4250615

Thanks for all the optimization-pointers!

Comment: Don't use `length someList == 0`. That is slow, since `length` needs to traverse the entire list. Use `null someList`, that can stop at the first found item.

Comment: Thanks, @DanielFischer. It seems faster. Not enough though.

Comment: Create a set of prime numbers and check whether a number is in this set, instead of testing for divisibility each time. Prime numbers up to 10^6 will be enough.

Comment: @tobias_k: So doing something like this: https://gist.github.com/4250323 ? This will give me a set of primes which I can then just check in if a number exists. But that expression is still too slow if it has to find the first million primes.

Comment: That's actually not necessary here. But [in principle](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/arithmoi) it can be done.

Comment: It's not obvious to me why numbers starting with a 5 cannot be truncatable primes. Indeed, 53 is a truncatable prime, no?

Comment: @tobias_k: ah, yeah, that makes the list quite smaller :) I will look at Sieve of Eratosthenes, thanks!

Comment: @dave4420: Ah, dunno, I must have misread something and gotten in to my head that primes cannot contain the digit 5.

Comment: @chrisbuchholz If any digit other than the first is a 5 then you will get a non-prime multiple of 5 at some point when truncating from the right. (If the first digit is a 5 then you finish with a *prime* multiple of 5 when truncating from the right.)

Comment: `(drop 1)` is better known as `tail`... :) And `truncateListRight xs = take (length xs) $ ...` can be written as `takeWhile (not.null)` to better represent the _intent_ behind the code (and `prime` perhaps is better named `isPrime`, by the same token).

Comment: @WillNess: `drop 1` is usually preferred to `tail` since it does not crash on an empty list (although if you're sure your input list is non-empty, you might regard this as a disadvantage)

Comment: @BenMillwood but not if its iterated application is guarded by `takeWhile (not.null)`. :)

Comment: @WillNess: My personal opinion is that `drop 1` is so often better that one may as well use it all the time, to save me the trouble of working out why the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two errors in your code, first

```
Prelude Data.Char Main> truncatablePrime 3797
False
```

and second, your list comprehension conditions are not correct. (Hope that isn't too much of a spoiler.)

Comment: Ah yes, it seems that my assumption that a prime cannot contain the digit 5 was not correct. Also, I see what you are getting at. The thing that breaks with truncatablePrime 3797 is `prime 7973` which returns false. The rest of the "steps" return true though. So it is actually my prime function that is to blame.

Comment: No, the `prime` function is correct. You have a fault in your logic of truncatable primes.

Comment: Have I misunderstood the definition of what a truncatable prime is? Is the problem that is has to be truncatable from both ways, but not reversed? I guess I have made that requirement up my self.

Comment: Yes, that would work. You're testing the candidate twice, but that doesn't matter much in terms of performance here.

Comment: Yeah, it seems to run pretty fast now. I can get the sum of the first 10 truncatable primes in a couple of seconds now. The 11nth is still not accessible. I guess the next step is to implement Sieve of Erastosthenes.

Comment: You shouldn't need that, the largest truncatable primes isn't so large, it would only take a couple of seconds anyway. Have you corrected the 53 issue that dave4420 mentioned?

Comment: Go back to your old `prime` test. That's faster ;)

Comment: Indeed it is! How come that be? Also, if I run the main function in ghci, its really slow, whereas if I compile with ghc og -O2, its really fast. Some optimisations that are going on there!

Comment: In re ghci vs. `-O2`, ghci interprets the code (but if you compile it before loading it in ghci, the performance should not be too much worse than running the compiled executable). Regarding the prime tests, there are 78498 primes less than 10^6. Every time you check a non-prime, you traverse the entire list to compare. You could get okay performance if you made `primes` a `Data.Set` or `Data.IntSet`, then the membership test would be faster.

Comment: you can also start your GHCi as `ghci -fobject-code` and all code that you load in it (with `:l`) will be compiled. You can also type `:set -fobject-code` at the GHCi prompt once inside, to get the same effect. If you have `{-# OPTIONS_GHC -O2 #-}` as the first line in your source code file, those command line options will be in effect when compiling with ghc (not sure about compiled-loading though).

Comment: @AndrewC Because it's not a real answer, only a hint. Doesn't deserve any rep. (Yes, not quite what CW is intended for, don't tell anybody.)

Comment: @DanielFischer Your secret's safe with me.